# doesnot show any validation error messages in laravel5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have used this function in controller to store the records of the users with validations. The data is not stored if the validation is not met but it doesnot show any validation error message.

```
public function store()
  {

        $input = Input::all();
        $validation = Validator::make($input, User::$rules);

        if ($validation->passes())
        {
            User::create($input);

            return Redirect::route('users.index');
        }

        return Redirect::route('users.create')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validation)
            ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');
  }
```

I have the model:

```
<?php
namespace App;

class User extends BaseModel{

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'phone'
    ];


    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

  public static $rules = array(
    'name' => 'required|min:5',
    'email' => 'required|email');
}
```

`users.create` view file:

```
@extends('layouts.user')

@section('main')

<h1>Create User</h1>

{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'users.store')) }}
    <ul>

        <li>
            {{ Form::label('name', 'Name:') }}
            {{ Form::text('name') }}
        </li>

        <li>
            {{ Form::label('username', 'Username:') }}
            {{ Form::text('username') }}
        </li>

        <li>
            {{ Form::label('password', 'Password:') }}
            {{ Form::password('password') }}
        </li>

        <li>
            {{ Form::label('password', 'Confirm Password:') }}
            {{ Form::password('password_confirmation') }}
        </li>        

        <li>
            {{ Form::label('email', 'Email:') }}
            {{ Form::text('email') }}
        </li>

        <li>
            {{ Form::label('phone', 'Phone:') }}
            {{ Form::text('phone') }}
        </li>


        <li>
            {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn')) }}
        </li>
    </ul>
{{ Form::close() }}



@stop
```

Comment: Can you show the code in the view 'users.create'

Comment: Make sure you are showing the errors on your view {{ $errors }}

Comment: If not, then it might be that you're not using you view under the middleware group on your routes file.

Comment: if i use $error  it displays undefined variable where should i define? @Juakali92

Comment: try to use Requests it's much easier  i think
you can see the docs for more information https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: @maximl337 ok. added that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from Laravels [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation)

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: f i use $error it displays undefined variable where should i define?

Comment: You don't define this, Laravel will always check for errors in the session data, and automatically bind them to the view if they are available using $errors. I would suggest posting your routes file. Make sure this view is under 
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    
});

in your routes file

Comment: providing you are using 5.2 not 5.1 laravel

Comment: @jukali92 i am using laravel 5.2 and my route is just: 

`Route::resource('users', 'UserController');`

Comment: @jukali92 oh yes. the route should be under web middleware group: `Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () { 
 Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
});`